# How to merge two hashes and remove extra elements

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I have this hash:

```
a={a: 'a', b: 'b'}
```

and this hash:

```
b={c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'e'}
```

And I want to merge them, but since hash `a` only contains two keys, I want to make sure I only keep the two initial keys of hash `b`, so instead of this:

```
a.merge b
=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d", :e=>"e"}
```

I would like a result that looks like this:

```
=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d" }
```

so I kept the first two hash keys of `b`, since `a` only had two hash keys. If `a` had three hash keys, then we would have kept all three of `b`'s, and so forth.

The documentation shows a [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-delete) method, but it forces me to specify a key. I won't know what the key is, I just want to remove extra elements.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
Hash[a.to_a + b.to_a[0...a.length]]
# or 
Hash[a.to_a + b.to_a.take(a.length)]
```

Turn to array then slice `b` by `a`'s length, turn to hash at last.

Comment: @oldergod That's better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, assuming none of `b`'s keys are in `a`:

```
a = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
b = { c: 'c', d: 'd', e: 'e' }

keepers = b.keys[0,a.size]
  #=> [:c, :d]
a.merge(b.select { |k,_| keepers.include?(k) })
  #=> {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c", :d=>"d"}
```

Note that it has only been since Ruby version 1.9 that hashes have maintained the insertion order of keys.